# How to find String from attribute proxyAddresses?

Tags: active-directory, powershell-4.0

How to find string "SMTP:*" (primary user address) in attributte `proxyAddresses`, then save in to variable and compare with value in attribute company. If there is  a match (or no match) then exported into CSV file.

The number of values proxyAddresses is different:
`smtp:adam@ff.ju.com,SMTP:adam@zf.ju.com,smtp:adam@ju.com`
or
`smtp:adam@ff.ju.com,SMTP:adam@ef.ju.com`
or
`SMTP:adam@ff.ju.com`

Values in attributte company are only two characters: `ff` or `zf` or `ju`. They are always two characters after the `@`.

I have about two thousand users in Active Directory.

I have a code

```psh
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'DC=ju,DC=com' -Properties company,proxyaddresses |
  select company, @{L='ProxyAddress'; E={$_.proxyaddresses -join"; "}}
```

Result is a column `Company` (two char) and a column `proxyaddresses` (there are all values). I need only the value `SMTP:xxx@xxx`.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what *specific* problem do you need help with? SO is not a place where other people write code for you.

Comment: I have a code Get-ADUser  -Filter * -SearchBase 'DC=ju,DC=com' -Properties company,proxyaddresses | select company, @{L='ProxyAddress'; E={$_.proxyaddresses -join"; "}} RESULT is column Company (two char) and Column proxyaddresses (there are all values). I need only value SMTP:xxx@xxx

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, as it tends to become unreadable. Edit your question instead (this time I took the liberty of doing it for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the `proxyaddresses` element that begins with an uppercase `SMTP:`:

```
@{n='ProxyAddress';e={$_.proxyaddresses | Where-Object {$_ -clike 'SMTP:*'} | Select-Object -First 1}}
```

The operator `-clike` does a case-sensitive comparison.